# Proving the possibility of building a three-colorable graph with n vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I want to show that, for every number n, it is possible to build a three-colorable graph with n vertices and $\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{3} \right\rfloor$ edges. I also want to show that if you have any more edges than $\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{3} \right\rfloor$, it becomes impossible to do.

I see the pattern on how to build this three-colorable graph for a given n. I'll use n = 7 as an example. This will have 7 vertices and 16 edges. The first thing is to split the n vertices as evenly as possible into three colors (for n = 7 you could say 3 red, 2 blue, and 2 green). Then, each red can have an edge with each green and each blue and stay consistent with the problem (3 red * 2 blue * 2 green for 12 edges). Then each blue vertex can have an edge with each green vertex (2 blue * 2 green for 4 more edges, giving us 16 total).

This has worked for all n I have tried, so I think this is a fine pattern. My question comes in mathematically explaining why having another edge would make this impossible. I definitely see why (to add another edge it would have to be two vertices with the same color), but I don't know if there is a way to expand $\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{3} \right\rfloor$ to show this, or if just explaining how this would break the pattern would be sufficient.

Comment: Two things. (1) Ultimately, the upper bound of $\lfloor \frac{n^2}{3} \rfloor$ is shown in the same way as the upper bound of $\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4}\rfloor$ to your earlier question. (2) Proving an upper bound means proving more than just "having another edge would make this impossible" - it means that even if someone tried a completely different approach than the one you started with, they would still run up against the same limit of $\frac{n^2}{3}$.

Comment: I see. I thought it might be similar, but wasn't quite getting the three in the denominator, so I did not know if this was done differently. I will try again.